# SharePoint Accordion List View Webpart filter automatically scrolls to top

Tags: javascript, list-view, css

I have some 10+ list view webparts inside 5 different web part zones. Each zone is inside a accordion header. When I filter any of the list view web part the action menu is created somewhere at the top and is not fully visible. Also it automatically scrolls to the top where the action menu is displayed.

I have tried setting `position:relative; z-index:999` for the CSS class of the action menu `ms-core-menu-box` but i still cant make the action menu fully visible. I need a solution where the action menu doesn't scroll the window to top and gets displayed near the column header

Answer (score 0):

instead of `position: relative` you have to use `position: absolute`. By default, MS set following inline property for `.ms-core-menu-box`:

```
position: absolute; top: calculated in px; left: calculated in px; width: in px; height: in px.
```

You need to inspect your HTML elements (from web part zone wrapper to the List view web part div) and figure out where the wrapper element `position` is changing from `relative` to something else. If this is case, than please update the position to relative and your problem will be solved.